# Prevent accidental test connection string merge on master

Tags: azure-devops

today during a merge of a PR due to a distraction a PR with a production connection string went on the Azure DevOps repo and so we had a test environment pointing to production.

We are migrating the process of commit/deployments but I was wondering if it's possible to specify a check in the commit process to avoid an accidental error of this kind.

Is this somehow possible?
Thanks

Comment: This is more of a development practices issue. Write your application so that configuration is sourced from a configuration management system such as Azure App Configuration or Azure KeyVault, rather than relying on connection strings in files.